# "Generalized" monotonicity of the expected value

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables
with cumulative distribution functions $F_X(t)$ and $F_Y(t)$ respectively.

Suppose that 
$\forall t \in \mathbb{R} \ F_X(t) \geq F_Y(t)$.
Does it imply that $E(X) \leq E(Y)$?

Note that $X \leq Y$ implies $F_X(t) \geq F_Y(t)$ but not vise versa:

1. $X \leq Y$ $\ \Rightarrow \ $ $F_Y(t) = P(Y \leq t) \leq P(X \leq t) = F_X(t)$.
2. If $X$ has the standard normal distribution and $Y=-X$, then $F_X(t) = F_Y(t)$ but $X$ can be greater than $Y$.

Comment: Yes. For example, you can couple $X$ and $Y$ so that $Y-X\geq 0$ always -  e.g. let $U$ be uniform on $[0,1]$ and set $X=F_X^{-1}(U)$, $Y=F_Y^{-1}(U)$. Then $E(Y-X)$ is certainly non-negative so $EX\leq EY$. 

Comment: Note that $X$ and $Y$ can be independent as well,
and $F_X(t) \geq F_Y(t)$ does not imply that $X \leq Y$.
I added an example to the question.

Comment: That's not James Martin's point (I believe). You are basically asking a question about distribution functions (the distribution function determines a measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and from this you get the expectation). So if you can find *any* random variables X, Y with the distributions $F_X$ and $F_Y$ such that $E(X) \le E(Y)$, then the statement must be true for *all* random variables with these distributions. And James Martin's comment shows how to construct such $X, Y$.

Comment: By the way, is there any textbook or article, in which this property is listed? I have looked in several textbooks but have not found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) d x = -x (1-F(x))\vert_{-\infty}^\infty +\int_{-\infty}^\infty (1-F(x))d x.$

From this you should be able to deduce conditions under which the answer to your question is in the affirmative.

Using monotone convergence for the integrals on $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$, we obtain:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) dx = \lim_{R \to \infty} \left( -x (1-F(x))\vert_{-R}^R +\int_{-R}^R (1-F(x))d x \right)
$$

By monotony of limits, we obtain the result if a probability density function and the first moment exist.

Comment: Since $F(-\infty) = 0$, both summands diverge, so I do not see any advantage of this representation.

Comment: They only diverge is the support is unbounded.

Comment: Yes, if the support is bounded, this formula answers the question.
Additionally, if the second moment exists then
$1-F_X(t) \leq E(X^2)/t^2$ from Chebyshev's inequality,
so that the limit and the integral exist even if the upper bound is infinite.
And since integration by parts can be applied to the Riemann–Stieltjes integral, this formula holds for an arbitrary random variable (not only continuous) 